# serialization error with system.numerics.complex (MONO environment)

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, mono

I have an error about serialization of complex numbers in MONO. If I run the same code in a Microsoft .NET environment I have no error at all.

I'm using a binary formatter, and this is the function using it:

```
public static void dump_to_file(List<QuantumOperator> obj, string custom_filename = "")
    {
        if (custom_filename.Length > 0)
        {
            custom_filename = "-" + custom_filename;
        }
        var filename = filename_prefix + "-" + filename_suffix + custom_filename + ".pickle";
        Console.WriteLine("Begin writing file: " + filename);
        var binform = new BinaryFormatter();
        var f = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        binform.Serialize(f, obj);
        f.Close();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Writing time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString() + " seconds.");
        Console.WriteLine("Write done. Closing file.");
    }
```

I have this error running with MONO (under linux with "mono-sgen"):

Unhandled Exception:
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type System.Numerics.Complex is not marked as Serializable.
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryCommon.CheckSerializable (System.Type type, ISurrogateSelector selector, StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.GetObjectData (System.Object obj, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.TypeMetadata& metadata, System.Object& data) [0x00000] in :0

but if I compile it with Visual Studio (2013) I have no problem at all, as I said.

I'm not a C# expert, I'm started to code two weeks ago, so I have no idea how to fix this problem.
I tried to create a custom Complex class (marked as serializable) derived from system.numerics.complex, but .NET is no happy with this solution, because system.numerics.complex is a sealed class.

thanks in advance,
Fausto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in mono. Mono does not have `[Serializable]` attribute for System.Numerics.Complex type while MS .NET has.

[System.Numerics.Complex from mono source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Numerics/System.Numerics/Complex.cs)

[System.Numerics.Complex from MS.NET source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Numerics/System/Numerics/Complex.cs)

As a workaround you can download one of these files, add `[Serializable]` attribute and add the file to your project using conditional compilation instructions. (`#if MONO`  ... source file here... `#endif`). Then add to your solution profile `MONO`, which defines `MONO` in project settings. In that case you'll have to complie two different .exe files - one for MS.NET platform and another one for Mono platform, but at least serialization should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I used the mono source and I added the Serializable attribute, but now I have some problems with "Version". This is the error:

/home/philo/SKT/SKT/sktlibs.cs(71,71): Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `System.Numerics.Complex[,] [SKT, Version=1.0.5444.26207, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]' expression to type `System.Numerics.Complex[,] [System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]' (CS1503) (SKT)

I also tried to create a new type but Mathnet.Numerics doesn't know it, and I have a lot of probs to use it.

Comment: the code generating that error is:

  public static Matrix<Complex> matrifixy(Complex[,] ar)
  {
   return (MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Complex.DenseMatrix.OfArray(ar));
  }

Comment: That's because third-party library references System.Numerics assembly. If you aren't going to deliver your application to other users, the most easy solition is to compile mono from source code (with [Sezializable] attribute added to the file). Or you can create dll project System.Numerics in your solution, place the Complex type here and add AssemblyInfo.cs file with required version

Comment: thanks a lot. Maybe compiling mono from source should be easier for me. The second option is too much advance for my actual skills. :)

Comment: That workaround worked for me. Now, I hope, in the next version of MONO that behaviour will be the default.